# In D3 bar graph, y-axis ordinal scale is not aligning properly with bars

Tags: javascript, d3.js, graph

I was following [Mike's tutorial Let's make a bar graph](https://bost.ocks.org/mike/bar/) [part II](https://bost.ocks.org/mike/bar/2/), [part III](https://bost.ocks.org/mike/bar/3/) for the bar graph in d3.
I end up with a horizontal bar graph.
The Problem is I'm not able to set the y-axis labels aligned with its respective bar, maybe I'm somewhere wrong with ordinal scale or setting up the y position of the bars.
Also, the graph bars are starting from the top instead of baseline.

```js
 var options = {
   margin: {
     top: 0,
     right: 30,
     bottom: 0,
     left: 50
   },
   width: 560,
   height: 400,
   element: 'body',
   colors: ["#f44336", "#e91e63", "#673ab7", "#3f51b5", "#2196f3", "#03a9f4", "#00bcd4", "#009688", "#4caf50", "#8bc34a", "#cddc39", "#ffeb3b", "#ffc107", "#ff9800", "#ff5722", "#795548", "#607d8b"]
 };

 options.mWidth = options.width - options.margin.left - options.margin.right;
 options.mHeight = options.height - options.margin.top - options.margin.bottom;

 var _colorScale = d3.scale.ordinal()
   // .domain([minValue,maxValue])
   .range(options.colors);
 var items = Math.round((Math.random() * 10) + 3);
 var data = [];
 for (var i = 0; i < items; i++) {
   data.push({
     label: 'label' + i,
     value: Math.random() * 100
   });
 }

 var _barThickness = 20;

 var width = options.mWidth,
   height = options.mHeight;

 var svg = d3.select(options.element)
   .append("svg")
   .attr("width", width).attr("height", height)
   .attr("viewBox", "0 0 " + options.width + " " + options.height)
   //.attr("preserveAspectRatio", "xMinYMin meet")
   .append("g");

 svg.attr("transform", "translate(" + options.margin.left * 2 + "," + options.margin.top + ")");

 var maxValue = 0,
   minValue = 0;
 for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
   maxValue = Math.max(maxValue, data[i].value);
   minValue = Math.min(minValue, data[i].value);
 }

 var scales = {
   x: d3.scale.linear().domain([0, maxValue]).range([0, width / 2]),
   y: d3.scale.ordinal().rangeRoundBands([0, height], .1)
 }

 scales.y.domain(data.map(function(d) {
   return d.label;
 }));

 var bars = svg.append("g")
   .attr("class", "bar");

 var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
   .scale(scales.x)
   .orient("bottom")
   .ticks(5);

 var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
   .scale(scales.y)
   .orient("left");

 var xaxis = svg.append("g")
   .attr("class", "x axis")
   .attr('transform', 'translate(' + 0 + ',' + height + ')')
   .call(xAxis)
   .append("text")
   .attr("x", width / 2)
   .attr("dy", "3em")
   .style("text-anchor", "middle")
   .text("Durations in hours");

 var yaxis = svg.append("g")
   .attr("class", "y axis")
   .attr('transform', 'translate(' + 0 + ',' + 0 + ')')
   .call(yAxis)
   .append("text")
   .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
   .attr("y", -options.margin.left)
   .attr("x", -height / 2)
   .attr("dy", ".71em")
   .style("text-anchor", "middle")
   .text("Labels");

 var bar = bars.selectAll('rect.bar').data(data);
 var rect = bar.enter()
   .append('g')
   .attr('transform', function(d, i) {
     return 'translate(0,' + parseInt(i * _barThickness + 2) + ')';
   });

 rect.append('rect')
   .attr('class', 'bar')
   .attr('fill', function(d) {
     return _colorScale(d.value);
   })

 .attr('width', function(d) {
     return scales.x(d.value);
   })
   .attr('height', _barThickness - 1)
   .attr('y', function(d, i) {
     return (i * _barThickness);
   })
  rect.append('text')
   .attr('x', function(d) {
     return scales.x(d.value) + 2;
   })
   .attr('y', function(d, i) {
     return (i * _barThickness);
   })
   .attr('dy', '0.35em')
   .text(function(d) {
     return Math.round(d.value);
   });
```

```css
svg {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
text {
  font-size: 0.8em;
  line-height: 1em;
}
path.slice {
  stroke-width: 2px;
}
polyline {
  opacity: .3;
  stroke: black;
  stroke-width: 2px;
  fill: none;
}
.axis {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
}
.axis path,
.axis line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.17/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Problem 1:**

Instead of this:

```
  var _barThickness = 20;
```

Do this:

```
  var _barThickness = scales.y.rangeBand();
```

Read [here](https://github.com/d3/d3-3.x-api-reference/blob/master/Ordinal-Scales.md#ordinal_rangeRoundBands)

If you want to regulate the thickness

Instead of this:

```
y: d3.scale.ordinal().rangeRoundBands([0, height], .1)
```

Do this:

```
y: d3.scale.ordinal().rangeRoundBands([0, height], .7)
```

**Problem 2:**

Incorrect transform.

Instead of this:

```
var rect = bar.enter()
  .append('g')
  .attr('transform', function(d, i) {
    return 'translate(0,' + parseInt(i * _barThickness + 2) + ')';
  });
```

Do this:

```
var rect = bar.enter()
  .append('g');
```

**Problem 3:**

Incorrect calculation of y for the bars.

```
  .attr('y', function(d, i) {
    return (i * _barThickness);
  })
```

Do this:

```
  .attr('y', function(d, i) {
    return scales.y(d.label);
  })
```

working code [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/T9eLHsUTIUV2BGsWkB1o?p=preview)

Comment: Thank you, It is working fine, but next thing when I update the data in the bar graph, instead of updating the values, it redraws the graph over the previous one. here is updated fiddle link https://jsfiddle.net/ankibalyan/hr3rrjtp/ when you click on the bars it should updates its children data.

Comment: i believe its another question on SO.